# Swipe from list item to delete data from database

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created a listview and Once the data is retrieved from the database it is displayed in that listview.
I want to swipe the listview items to delete the data from the database and want the updated data to be shown in listview.
I could bot achieve in this..plz help.

**showRecords()** which is used to display the data from the database

```
function showRecords() 
{
var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM  list ORDER BY subject";

db.transaction(function (tx) {

    tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {
    var dataset = result.rows.length;
    var combinelist='';

    for (var i = 0;  i < dataset; i++) 
    {

        res = result.rows.item(i);
        var Lid=res.id;
        var Lsubject=res.subject;
        var Ldesc=res.desc;
        var Ldate=res.date;
        combinelist+='<li id="lists" rel="'+Lid+'" style="border-bottom:solid; background:#CFF">' + Lsubject + '<br>' + Ldesc + '<br>' + Ldate + '<br>' + '<a href="#" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" onclick="loadRecord('+Lid+');" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" id="editbtn"> Edit</a></li>';
            $("#showlist").html(combinelist).listview('refresh');
             }
          });
        });
      }
```

code for the **listview**..

```
<center><h2> To-Do List</h2></center>
<ul id="showlist" data-role="listview">
</ul>
```

**Pageinit**

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#pageone",function(){
localStorage.Lid=Lid;
alert(Lid);
$( "ul_showlist" ).on( "swiperight", swipeHandler );
function swipeHandler(){
alert("hello");;

var sql='DELETE FROM list WHERE id='+Lid+'';
  db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql,showRecords); alert("Delete Sucessfully"); });
}
});
```

Comment: There's a demo --- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/swipe-list/ --copy the code and modify it for your project.

Comment: But i want to delete the list items which are retrieved from the database..

Comment: what is the issue you are facing??

Comment: I could not swipe and delete the records which was retrieved from the database and shown in the form of list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks could able to swipe and delete the records..

```
    $('#showlist #lists').on("swiperight",swiperight_list);

    function swiperight_list(event)
    {
    var Lid=$(this).attr('rel');
    var sql='DELETE FROM list WHERE id='+Lid+'';
    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql); 
    alert("Delete Sucessfully"); });
    }
```